# convert values in a series to either one of two values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a series y which has values between -3 and 3.

I want to convert numbers that are above 0 to 1 and numbers that are less than or equal to zero to 0.

What is the best way to do this?

I wrote the code below. However it doesn't give me the expected output. The first line works. However after running the second line the values that were 1 change to something random, which I don't understand

```
import numpy as np
y_final = np.where(y > 0, 1, y).tolist()
y_final = np.where(y <= 0, 0, y).tolist()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need [`Series.clip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.clip.html) if values are integers:

```
y = pd.Series(range(-3, 4))
print (y)
0   -3
1   -2
2   -1
3    0
4    1
5    2
6    3
dtype: int64

print (y.clip(lower=0, upper=1))
0    0
1    0
2    0
3    0
4    1
5    1
6    1
dtype: int64
```

In your solution is possible simplify it by set `1` and `0`:

```
y_final = np.where(y > 0, 1, 0)
print (y_final)
[0 0 0 0 1 1 1]
```

Or convert mask greater like `0` to integers:

```
y_final = y.gt(0).astype(int)
#alternative
#y_final = (y > 0).astype(int)
print (y_final)
0    0
1    0
2    0
3    0
4    1
5    1
6    1
dtype: int32
```

Comment: I just tried the clip with lower =0 and upper = 1. It works for most numbers however there are some numbers like 0.93 which haven't changed. I'm guessing I should have been more precise in my question. The numbers range from -3 to 3 but are not only integers. cheers

Comment: You are correct, thanks I just needed to change my second line, to y_final, thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

You can also use simple map:

```py
numbers = range(-3,4)
print(list(map(lambda n: 1 if n > 0 else 0, numbers)))
```